# Is there a way to include a mixin as a variable

Tags: sass

I just tried to save me some time, generating some helper css classes for different breakpoints.

What I tried:

```
@mixin resp { width: 100%; height: auto;}
@mixin table { display: table}
@mixin trow { display: table-row}
@mixin tcell  { display: table-cell; }
@mixin gutter1px  { padding: 0 1px; }

$tools: resp, table, trow, tcell, gutter1px;

@mixin make-tools($breakpoint) {
  @each $tool in $tools {
    $i: index($tools, $tool);
    .#{$tool}-$breakpoint { @include #{$tool}(); }
  }
}

@media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) {
  @include make-tools(xs);
}
```

But this dosent seem to work:
@include #{$tool}();

Has anyone an idea how to archive that, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Hate to break it to you but using interpolation for `mixin` or `function` identifier is not possible in Sass

Comment: Yes I thought so, too bad.